# How set custom Row Total in Checkout page(Order Summery Block) in Magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, checkout-page

Checkout Shipping address page I need set custom item row total..how can i do???
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your js file (it can be your extended uiComponent):

```
    define(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder',
            'mage/storage',
            'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'
        ],
        function ($, quote, urlBuilder, storage, customer) {
            'use strict';

            return function (deferred, messageContainer) {
                var serviceUrl;
                /**
                 * Checkout for guest and registered customer.
                 */
                if (!customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                    serviceUrl = urlBuilder.createUrl('/guest-carts/:cartId/payment-information', {
                        cartId: quote.getQuoteId()
                    });
                } else {
                    serviceUrl = urlBuilder.createUrl('/carts/mine/payment-information', {});
                }

                storage.get(
                    serviceUrl, false
                ).done(
                    function (response) {
                        // set items totals
                        response.totals.items.forEach(function (item, index) {
                            item.row_total = 0;
                            item.row_total_incl_tax = 0;
                            item.row_total_with_discount = 0;
                        });

                        quote.setTotals(response.totals);
                    }
                ).fail(
                    function (response) {
                        //
                    }
                );
            };
        }
    );
```